# Touchscreen functionality for Kogan Atlas C250 / Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: 20.04, touchscreen

I've just installed Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS on a new [Kogan Atlas C250](https://www.kogan.com/au/buy/kogan-atlas-116-c250-convertible-laptop/)

Is there a way to get the touchscreen working?  I've tried to search but found nothing specific that helped.  I've also followed the [touchscreen wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touchscreen) serial connection steps with not much luck. (I keep getting [screen is terminating] at the 'screen /dev/ttyS_' step).

The dream is to be able to flip the screen around to tablet mode and annotate PDFs.

In case this is valuable information - the login page appears upside down every time (if anyone has a fix so I don't have to screenlock on every reboot, it would be appreciated too)

Thank you

P.S. Ubuntu has made this cheap machine usable...  The machine was running at CPU 100% constantly using the pre-installed windows... before I even opened any other program! Ubuntu is barely at 30% by comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing the same thing you are..
Did you have any luck with the touch screen or lock screen?

Theres mentions of this in a whirlpool thread but no clear answer for us yet. I might make a post

https://forums.whirlpool.net.au/thread/96rk8jy9#r64802458